# How to specify a date value parameter in Toad for an Oracle Query using the query parameter window?

Tags: oracle11g, toad

In the following hard coded query I have two varchar2 params and two date params.

```
select * from myTable
where title = 'abc'
and start_date = TO_DATE('04/05/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
and end_date = TO_DATE('04/06/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
and description = 't';
```

This query returns two rows.

When I run the same query using the Toad query parameter value entry window

```
select * from myTable
where title = :ttitle 
and start_date = :startdate
and end_date = :enddate 
and description = :descrip;
```

I enter  abc  for the ttitle param, 2016/04/05 for the startdate, 2016/04/06 for the enddate and  t  for the description.  Then I receive the following error for the date params

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

I have tried other variations for the date '04/05/2016', I tried the entire TO_DATE('04/05/2016'....), ... and other formats, but keep getting errors.  Note:  if I comment out the date params and just use the varchar2 params, the query runs when I enter in   abc   and    t.  My problem is with the date params.  What is the correct way to enter the date values in the parameter window for Toad?

Answer (score 0):

Try `'DD-MON-YYYY'` for the date format  i.e. `'08-APR-2016'`.  I believe it needs to match the NLS_DATE_FORMAT as set in your session:

To see your NLS_DATE_FORMAT:

```
SELECT value
FROM   nls_session_parameters
WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
```

You can also change the date format for your session so a date entered like this will be considered a date and no TO_DATE will be needed.

```
ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```